# Drupal 7 jquery block displaying as text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drupal, drupal-7

I'm having a lot of trouble adding a jQuery block. I've searched every forum and tried a ton of solutions but no matter what it always ends up displaying as html text in the header.

Is there anything wrong with the code I've written in the block?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

(function ($) {

   var leftInit = $("#logo-scroll").offset().left;
   var top =$("#logo-scroll").offset().top;

   $(window).scroll(function(event) {
    var x = 0 - $(this).scrollLeft();
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();

    $("#logo-scroll").offset({
    left: x + leftInit
    });

});

})(jQuery);


</script>
```

If I call upon the library it displays that as html as well, but it appears to be already called upon when I inspect the page and my code doesn't look any different than other js or jq blocks that are already built and being used.

Granted I'm not very familiar with jQuery, but it works in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/F7Bme/1184/

I have no access to the backend .js files, so it has to be put into a block.

Any guidance would be appreciated, this is frustrating me to no end.

Comment: Although nobody likes PHP filter 'cause of security reasons, one of my backup sites uses it, and it works perfectly there. Your choice.

Answer (score 1):

FULL HTML does not work with Javascript.

You will need to enable the core PHP Filter module, and then you can change the input format to PHP code, and everything will work as you desire (providing your javascript code is correct).

The full html filter does not allow for javascript.

This said now, you might want to include any extra javascript like this in a .js include file with your theme.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried your code in a block on a D7 site and it did not display in the HTML. I had Full HTML selected as the formatting. If the formatting somehow got set to Filtered, etc, that would produce the problem you are having.

Update: here is a screenshot from Firebug. I also tested a basic document.write("hello");in the same block, and it rendered on the page as expected.
[image]